# Union queries causing type conversion error

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion, union

I'm trying to work out why my union queries are giving me type conversion errors

I am trying to create a report that has to be formatted in a way that multiple union queries seems like the easiest option.
Essentially I want an output that shows the key column, and then a row for each other column, and the value for that column, so it would kind of look like this:

```
Key1  Column1   Value
Key1  Column2   Value
Key2  Column1   Value
Key2  Column2   Value
```

I'm doing this for about 40 columns though, so its a lot of select statements.

All of my select statements are structured the same:

```
SELECT tb1.Key AS 'Key', 'Column1' AS 'Column', tb1.Column1 AS 'Value'
union
SELECT tb1.Key AS 'Key', 'Column2' AS 'Column', tb1.Column2 AS 'Value'
```

etc

When running all of the queries individually I have no issue, but when I try to run all, of them I get an issue converting various strings to type int.

In order to try rectifying this I've tried casting every 'value' column as NVARCHAR and I still get an error that some of the strings are trying to be converted to type int, but I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: The problem is the queries themselves and the column types, not `UNION`.  Casting to `nvarchar` doesn't rectify anything, it tries to cover up the actual problem while introducing far more serious problems like localization issues - what do dates look like after that? Numbers? Worse, if that query is used in a view, the server won't be able to use any indexes on the columns

Comment: Please post the *actual* queries and the table schemas. The problem is the column types, not `UNION`. What reporting tool are you using too? Perhaps the easiest way to do what you want is to let the report tool merge the queries

Comment: PS `UNION` performs an expensive `DISTINCT` operation. Use `UNION ALL` if you don't want to eliminate duplicates

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos. The query will not be used in a view so I don't have to worry about that, it just needs to be exported in this format. There are no dates, only strins and numbers in the columns. I might be misunderstanding CAST but if I cast as nvarchar why does it still try to convert to int?

Comment: It doesn't. You're asking people to guess what your queries and columns look like

Comment: Besides casting as any text type *formats* any non-text values. You *do* have to worry about 9/11 vs 11/9, or 4/7 vs 7/4. You may end up with strings that match the *server's* collation instead of the end user's locale, without the ability to fix it short of parsing the text back into actual numbers and dates

Comment: I'm not asking people to fix my code, I'm asking for help understanding using union works with columns of multiple data types so that I can solve this myself. I appreciate the lack of code table schema makes it difficult to understand the issue, but I don't understand why CASTing the selects that return an int to a string does not alleviate this issue.

Comment: The easy answer is because you missed a cast, or used it no the wrong thing. Other than that, how can anyone guess?

Comment: Ok it seems like this may not be the right way to go about it then, I'll look for an alternative. I'll try using the report tool, thanks fo rthat suggestion

Comment: No, it means you haven't provided any information that can be used to help you. The only thing one can do is give generic debugging advice. Try commenting out lines until you find out *which* query causes the problem. Start by commenting out half of the columns, then another half etc until you get to a set of queries that *do* work. Then add back the commented queries one by one until you find *one* that fails. Once you find that, try commenting out columns the same way

Answer (score 2):

Generally when doing a `UNION`, the data types of the columns of your result set will be determined by the first query that executes or returns rows.  So, if you're not sure which queries in the `UNIONs` return data you should `CAST` all your columns explicitly.  Something like:

```
SELECT 
  CAST(tb1.Key AS INTEGER) AS 'Key', 
  CAST('Column1' AS VARCHAR(100)) AS 'Column', 
  CAST(tb1.Column1 AS VARCHAR(100)) AS 'Value'
FROM MyTableA AS tb1

UNION

SELECT 
  CAST(tb1.Key AS INTEGER) AS 'Key', 
  CAST('Column1' AS VARCHAR(100)) AS 'Column', 
  CAST(tb1.Column1 AS VARCHAR(100)) AS 'Value'
FROM MyTableB AS tb1
```

If your `UNIONs` are simple `SELECTs` from the same table, it shouldn't be a problem.  But the issue may come up when some rows return `NULL` values and data types may not be what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the columns for a `union` need to be of the same type.  Typically, you can store values as strings.

More importantly, you don't need `union` for this.  SQL Server supports lateral joins using the `apply` keyword.  This is simpler to express as:

```
select tb1.key, v.column, v.value
from tb1 cross apply
     (values ('Column1', convert(nvarchar(max), tb1.Column1),
             ('Column2', convert(nvarchar(max), tb1.Column2),
             . . . 
     ) v(column, value);
```